# Avoiding statics across classes in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, static, static-methods

I - like many beginning programmers - am having trouble referencing a public, non-static method from across classes.  I am trying to build a game in JavaFX, and want to use a button from another class (call it Class B) to create a new game.  I know to create a new game I must use the following code in my main class (call it Class A):

```
stage.close();
start(stage);
```

Since stage is a non-static variable in Class A, I can not directly reference it in Class B.  To overcome this, I created the method shown below in Class A:

```
public void newGame() {
    stage.close();
    start(stage);
}
```

Since this is not (and cannot be) a static method, I can not directly reference this from Class B.  Therefore, to access the method, I generated the code below in Class B, where newGameBT is the button from Class B to create a new game:

```
newGameBT.setOnAction(e -> (new ClassA()).newGame());
```

When I run the program and click on the button, I get a Null Pointer Exception.  I believe the reason for this is because I am creating an entirely new class in my method call, causing some sort of error with scope, but I am not entirely sure of the full reason if my reason is even close to correct.

I have looked on many websites and found a solution like the one used here to be the "work-around" for static variables, but I can not seem to get it to work correctly.  So is there a way to work around this without making the button or the stage static?

Below is my current code excluding any unnecessary content:

Class A:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClassA extends Application {

    Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        this.stage = stage;

        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(50, 50, Color.RED);
        pane.add(r, 0, 0);
        pane.add(new ClassB(), 0, 1);

        // Create the primary scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show(); 

    }

    public void newGame() {
        stage.close();
        start(stage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Class B:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class ClassB extends Pane {

    public ClassB() {

        Button newGameBT = new Button("New Game");

        newGameBT.setOnAction(e -> (new ClassA()).newGame());

        getChildren().add(newGameBT);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is one of how to get a handle on a needed reference, and you are correct in thinking that assigning these references to static fields is bad, since this increases the coupling of your code, increases cyclomatic complexity and increases the risk of bugs.

Unfortunately there is no one-size-fits-all solution, and the best solution will depend on the overall structure of your program, something that we currently know little about. An "easy" solution is to simply pass around references to where they're needed, such as passing a reference to the currently visualized and running ClassA object to anywhere one needs to be able to call its methods, but this too increases coupling and complexity, and it is with an effort to decrease this coupling that many schemes have been created, including such design patterns as the Model-View-Controller (something I think that you should look int), as well as "dependency injection".

As a general bit of advice for a general question, I suggest that you start by looking into Model-View-Controller, and try to apply at least some of the principles to your program -- at least try to refactor the logic from the view. If you need more specific advice, then you're going to have to ask a more specific question, complete with your [minimal example program or MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I have added my code and am in the process of looking up MVC.